# Can someone explain this !/already exists/.test(err.message) method?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm following a firebase with react tutorial and I'm using try catch method to make sure my API keys work. Everything works in my code but I would like to have a deeper explanation of this method: !/already exists/.test(err.message)

Is it /already exists/.test from firebase docs?
And err.message is an object form js or firebase? Thank you so much for your help

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
}

try {
  console.log("FB", config)
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
} catch (err) {
  if (!/already exists/.test(err.message)) {
    console.error("Firebase initialization error", err.stack)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/already exists/` is a literal regular expression. You could also write it like this, to make it a bit more familiar to read:

```
!new RegExp("already exists").test(err.message)
```

So this code tests whether the error message contains "already exists", and ignores those (since they're likely harmless for the app).

---

On the Firebase front: I'd actually expect to *either* see the first three lines *or* the rest of the code, not both of them.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank! This is my first time being exposed to literal regular expressions, your explanation was very helpful. 

For firebase answer you mean the first three lines in the console?

Comment: I mean the code in your question: you either need the `if` block or the `try` block, not both.

Comment: Ohh yeah... you're right!! Did not think about it, thank youu